# what happened if i rm a file without unstaging it?

Tags: git, rm, unstage

lately, I've been learning git, then I came to the `git rm` that kind of confused me, I kept digging in and understood most of it, but there is a question still baffling me, what will happen if I deleted a file using the normal bash `rm` command without unstaging the removed file and then commit it? will the commit keep the file?

I've tried to do that myself but I couldn't see and understand the results.

Comment: have you tried it yourself?

Comment: yes but couldn't understand the result, my folder was messy and couldn't see the results.

Comment: Just create a new separate repo elsewhere in your fs to experiment in - all you need is `git init`.

Comment: See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm - you can use vanilla `rm` _"to remove a file only from the working tree and yet keep it in the index"_.

Answer (score 1):

Git builds new commits from whatever is in Git's index (aka staging-area).

If you remove a file from your working tree, but leave the copy of the file in the index, and then make a new commit, the new commit contains the file, because the file is there in Git's index.  The file continues *not* to exist in your working tree, because committing does not update your working tree.

Note that running `git add -u` or `git add file` will remove the file from Git's index.  The *next* commit will now lack the file, i.e., the difference between the *current* commit—which has the file—and the *next* commit will include "delete the given file".  So it's always a question of what's in Git's *index*, not what's in your working tree, and from there, a question of "what does this Git command do to Git's index".  Using `git rm` removes the file from Git's index, but—rather peculiarly—so can `git add`!

Comment: but `git add` is supposed to add files to the staging area not take them off of it, can you explain that more, please?

Comment: @elakhdar_ayoub: See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) for the way *they* put it, but the way I like to describe it is that `git add <file>` means "make the index copy of <file> match the working tree copy". That includes "working tree copy gone, so make index copy gone to match". It's weird and feels "wrong" to me so I use `git rm` instead, but it does actually *happen*. There's a `git add` flag to disable this.

Comment: that is actually helpful and interesting, thank you so much for your time.